# convert ascii character to signed 8-bit integer python

Tags: python, integer, ascii, signed

This feels like it should be very simple, but I haven't been able to find an answer..

In a python script I am reading in data from a USB device (x and y movements of a USB mouse). it arrives in single ASCII characters. I can easily convert to unsigned integers (0-255) using ord. But, I would like it as signed integers (-128 to 127) - how can I do this?

Any help greatly appreciated! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Subtract 256 if over 127:

```
unsigned = ord(character)
signed = unsigned - 256 if unsigned > 127 else unsigned
```

Alternatively, repack the byte with the `struct` module:

```
from struct import pack, unpack
signed = unpack('B', pack('b', unsigned))[0]
```

or directly from the character:

```
signed = unpack('B', character)[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from ctypes import c_int8
value = c_int8(191).value
```

use ctypes with your ord() value - should be -65 in this case

ex. from string data

```
from ctypes import c_int8
data ='BF'
value1 = int(data, 16) # or ord(data.decode('hex'))
value2 = c_int8(value1).value
```

value1 is 16bit integer representation of hex 'BF' and value2 is 8bit representation

Comment: Signed integer overflow is undefined in C, so this does not always work (But probably will in all versions of CPython)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I haven't found a satisfying answer elsewhere.

You can use the array module (with the extra convenience that it converts complete buffers):

```
from array import array

buf = b'\x00\x01\xff\xfe'
print(array('b', buf))

# result: array('b', [0, 1, -1, -2])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this function to get a signed 8bit integer value

```
def to8bitSigned(num): 
    mask7 = 128 #Check 8th bit ~ 2^8
    mask2s = 127 # Keep first 7 bits
    if (mask7 & num == 128): #Check Sign (8th bit)
        num = -((~int(num) + 1) & mask2s) #2's complement
    return num
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert any input bytes into signed integers:

```
def signed8bit_to_int(input):
    (((input >> 7) * 128) ^ input) - ((input >> 7) * 128)

Examples:
signed8bit_to_int(0xc0) = -64
signed8bit_to_int(0xbf) = -65
signed8bit_to_int(0x0f) = 15
```

Explanation with 0xC0 as an example:

- 0xc0  '0b1100 0000', its last bit is a 1, meaning it is a signed byte
- step 1: test for signed bit: (((input >> 7) * 128)
- step 2: if it is a signed bit, invert the input bites:
   from: 100 0000 to 0111 1111 (63 of base 10)
- step 3: convert the above by substantiating 128:
  63 - 128 = -65

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't clearly state if the single character is given as `str` or `bytes`.

The following answer is especially useful, if the input is an instance of `bytes`:
Since Python 3.2 there is a class method [`int.from_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes):

```
int.from_bytes(b'\x81', byteorder='big', signed=True)  # -127
int.from_bytes(b'a', byteorder='big', signed=True)  # 97
```

For 16-bit integers, one would simply pass 2 bytes instead of 1:

```
int.from_bytes(b'\x81\x80', byteorder='big', signed=True)  # -32384
int.from_bytes(b'ab', byteorder='big', signed=True)  # 24930
```

Of course, you may need to specify `byteorder='little'`.

However, if the input is an ASCII character (0 - 128), I don't understand why you want a signed integer, because the result for your input will always be positive anyway (if I'm not mistaken). Python's integers use a flexible amount of bytes.